# Integrating a custom built form with a subscriber list provider (Aweber)

Tags: wordpress, aweber

I have created my own form because every other form out there for `WordPress` is horrible.

```
div class="exc-form">
        <form action="action_page.php">
            <fieldset>
            <div id="form_jgrsh">
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Please enter first name">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Please enter last name">
            <br>
            Email:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter email">
            <div class="chk_bx">
            <input type="checkbox" name="concent" value="agree">By entering my information and pressing submit I agree to subscribing to the Stockhouse AND Junior Gold Report (please check box before submiting)
            <br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

It's super simple and isn't anything special. I'm under the impression `PHP` will be needed as well.

I use `Aweber` as my list provider, and I've contacted them for support and they want me to use their horrible, ugly form builder, and won't help me integrate my own form to use their list.

I've never done something like this before, so I'm looking for some guidance on how to send subscriber information to a list. `Aweber` offer's a list `ID` and most plugins I've seen require a `Aweber` authentication before `Aweber` links up to the list.

https://labs.aweber.com/snippets/lists - this is as closest to the resources I could find from `Aweber`.

Here is the authentication list: https://labs.aweber.com/snippets/authentication

Comment: People have done custom forms that link up with Aweber list services (it's semi the same concept as mailchimp), Aweber services that are paid for only offer support within their form building markups. 

I understand what you are saying, I just know that it CAN be done, I'm not sure how.